# selstart returns position 0 if text is entered in memo field (not clicked)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have memo field and list. What I want to accomplish is if I am typing something in memo field and then just click on text record in list that the text shows up in memo positioned with the beginning where cursor was.

After research, and googling I succeed to make it. I did it with .selstart property.

But for me it seems that selstart has bug. It works only if I click somewhere in memo (Then everything works great.) But if was typing something, and then click on text in list (without previously clicking in memo field) selstart returns position 0.

This makes me huge problem.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, the problem is that the cursor position is lost when you move away from the memo.
This is probably due to the fact that Access form controls are not "real" controls: they are real windows controls only when they have the focus. the rest of the time, they are sort of images of the control pasted onto the form.

So, what you need to do is track the cursor position (and currently selected length of text) during various interractions:

- when the user moves the cursor using the keyboard (`KeyUp` event)
- when the user clicks inside the memo (`Click` event, to position the cursor or select text using the mouse)
- when the memo initially gets the focus (`GetFocus`, the first time, the whole text is selected and the cursor is at position 0)

To test this, I made a small form:

[image: Test form]

The added the following code to the form:

```
'----------------------------------------------------------
' Track the position of the cursor in the memo
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private currentPosition As Long
Private currentSelLen As Long

Private Sub txtMemo_Click()
    RecordCursorPosition
End Sub

Private Sub txtMemo_GotFocus()
    RecordCursorPosition
End Sub

Private Sub txtMemo_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    RecordCursorPosition
End Sub

Private Sub RecordCursorPosition()
    currentPosition = txtMemo.SelStart
    currentSelLen = txtMemo.SelLength
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Insert when the user double-click the listbox or press the button
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub listSnippets_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    InsertText
End Sub

Private Sub btInsert_Click()
    InsertText
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------
' Do the actual insertion of text
'----------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub InsertText()
    If Len(Nz(listSnippets.Value, vbNullString)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Echo False 'Avoid flickering during update
    ' Update the Memo content
    Dim oldstr As String
    oldstr = Nz(txtMemo.Value, vbNullString)
    If Len(oldstr) = 0 Then
        txtMemo.Value = listSnippets.Value
    Else
        txtMemo.Value = Left$(oldstr, currentPosition) & _
                        listSnippets.Value & _
                        Mid$(oldstr, currentPosition + currentSelLen + 1)
    End If
    'We will place the cursor after the inserted text
    Dim newposition As Long
    newposition = currentPosition + Len(listSnippets.Value)
    txtMemo.SetFocus
    txtMemo.SelStart = newposition
    txtMemo.SelLength = 0
    currentPosition = newposition
    currentSelLen = 0
    Echo True
End Sub
```

I have made a [test accdb database that you can download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52900980/StackOverflow/SO18206776.accdb) so you can see the details and play around with this.

Comment: Although this stackoverflow comment box suggest to avoid comments to tell thank you, but I must. You really helped in such a great way. (explanations, example, uploaded file). Thank you man.